# Reception notification on UDP sockets

Tags: linux, sockets, signals

Is there any way to get the notification to application when there is a data arrived on UDP socket in LINUX?

I meant do we have any signals which does this job.

Many Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Yes** (although if one is pedantic about your wording, then no).

You *cannot* be notified when data arrives on an UDP socket, but you *can* be notified whenever the socket is ready.

The difference is that a datagram may arrive but is discarded (bad checksum, buffer full, etc), so you may never be able to read it. On some older Linux versions you could still get a readiness notification, but this has been fixed somewhere around an early version of 2.6. You should now only get a readiness notification when something is actually available to be read in the receive buffer. That is, you can do at least one `recvfrom` which isn't going to block (note that you can't really distinguish between "ready, 1 datagram available" and "ready, 10 datagrams available" other than by trying until you get `EAGAIN`).

There are several options for getting notified about readiness. The particular way you ask for can be obtained by using `fcntl` to set `O_ASYNC`, this requires a signal handler for `SIGIO`. See documentation: [[1]](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/socket.7.html) [[2]](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fcntl.2.html).

Alternatively, you can use `select` (most portable), `poll` (portable), or `epoll` (Linux only), which let your process block until an event happens.
This approach is what most people prefer since it doesn't involve singnal handlers and is generally more intuitive and user-friendly (providing e.g. level-triggered semantics).